# Block with firewall a dns request containing a certain query

Tags: networking, dns, firewall, iptables, packet

Example

let's say I'm with iptables or nftables

I want to allow a certain traffic like the following one:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.1 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.1 -p udp --sport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

can be the first rule be expanded including also the inspection of the packet containing the dns query and allowing only the packet containing ***.wetransfer.com** as query requested otherwise drop?

I think this should fall in what is called **Deep Packet Inspection**, but how can be done in terms of iptables/nftables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iptables does not understand DNS natively, but it should be possible using `string` match:

```
-p udp --dport 53 -m string --algo kmp --hex-string "|0A|wetransfer|03|com|00|" --icase
```

Note that DNS names on the wire do not use dots – they're sent as a series of length-prefixed components; e.g. ".com" is sent as `0x03 c o m`.

You must use a case-insensitive match (`--icase`) because clients might send the query in mixed-case (sometimes deliberately).